# How to get property of a class if class name is available only in string format?

Tags: swift

As a Swift beginner, I have defined the following class:

```
class Currency {
    var iso: String
    var name: String
    var country: String
    
    init(iso: String, name: String, country: String) {
        self.iso = iso
        self.name = name
        self.country = country
    }
}

let ccy1 = Currency(iso: "USD", name: "US-Dollar", country: "USA")
let ccy2 = Currency(iso: "EUR", name: "Euro", country: "Germany")
```

Each of the currency objects (`ccy1` and `ccy2`) contains a currency described by an ISO code and a name. It also contains a country where this currency is available.

For example, after a user query, I get the ISO code in string format and want to use it to output the currency name, e.g. with `currencyLabel.text = ccy1.name`. It would be even cooler if I could get the object name based on the ISO code, but not in string format, but of type Currency, so that I could access the properties of the object.

So how could I convert the string "ccy1" into the object `ccy1`? Alternatively, how can I infer the currency name or country based on the input string "USD"?

I already tried this idea:

```
let myClass = NSClassFromString("ccy1")
```

Unfortunately I didn't get anywhere with this snippet either:

```
Bundle.main.classNamed("MyClassName")
```

I hope this wasn't too confusingly expressed and someone can help.

Stephan

Comment: Keep the values into an array, or a dict, but don't try to access variables by its name, it's not recommended

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that. And don't use Objective-C related APIs for that purpose. Swift provides optimized APIs to query and filter large data sets.

First of all in Swift it's highly recommended to use a struct for a data model, it reduces your code to

```
struct Currency {
    let iso, name, country: String
}
```

The `init` method is for free. And as `iso`, `name` and `country` will likely never change declare them as constants.

Rather than creating a variable for each currency put the objects into an array

```
let currencies = [
    Currency(iso: "USD", name: "US-Dollar", country: "USA"),
    Currency(iso: "EUR", name: "Euro", country: "Germany")
]
```

and get a currency by the iso symbol with

```
if let eur = currencies.first(where: {$0.iso == "EUR}) { ... }
```

---

Or map the array to a dictionary for a more efficient lookup

```
let currencyTable = currencies.reduce(into: [String:Currency]()) { $0[$1.iso] = $1 }
```

and use it

```
if let eur = currencyTable["EUR"] { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you, this help a lot and will shorten the whole project.

Comment: Building up a table (once) is definitely the way to go here, makes the call sites much cleaner (and likely faster, depending on the exact number of currencies)

Comment: By the way, you can build up this dictionary using [Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/init(uniquekeyswithvalues:)): `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: currencies.map { (key: $0.iso, value: $0) })`